# Ubuntu login Screen broken and Unreadable

Tags: intel-graphics, 17.10

I used the install manager to upgrade to 17.10. Everything went well until my machine restarted. the boot-up screen (see boot-up screen) displayed correctly but when, I assume, the login screen appeared everything is unreadable. Hitting tab a few times and blindly entering my password I think I was able to log in but the screen still produced nothing readable.

[image: 1.boot up screen]

[image: 2.log-in screen]

Other info intel(R) Core TM2 6300 1.86GHz
64-bit technology
4.0GB RAM 800MHz

Any suggestions on how to fix this. I cannot remote into using putty. Someone mentioned a serial session, any other suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of graphics card do you have?

Comment: @OrganicMarble - top of page 3
 https://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/optix/en/opti_745techspecs.pdf

Comment: There are several graphics cards listed there. How about you just edit your question to say what kind of graphics card you have.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - will do sorry for confusion

Comment: @OrganicMarble - ATI Radeon X1300 256MB DMS59 DVI PCI-E Express x16, I looked up the part number.

Comment: As an update I installed Debian 9.2, no issues there. I never could figure out what caused the screen issue.